# python - check if word is in list full of strings and if there is print the words in an another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

so basically it would be like:

```
MyList=["Monkey","Phone","Metro","Boom","Feet"]
```

and let's say I have the input be **m** so Boo**m** and **M**onkey and **M**etro would be put in a list like so

```
output >> ["Monkey","Metro","Feet"]
```

and if I would've had the input be **f** then the output would be

```
output >> ["Feet"]
```

and my question is how would I put this in a def? This is what I came up with

```
def Find(word,MyList):
    MyList2=[]
    count=0
    for i in MyList:
        count+=1     
        if i[count] == MyList2:     ##(at first i did if i[0:10])
            for x in range(1):
                MyList2.append(i)
    print(MyList2)
```

and then somewhere there should be

```
word=input("Word, please.")
```

and then

```
Find(word,MyList)
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: The input alphabet can be present in at any index of a word in mylist, correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
def find_words(input_char, my_list):
    ret_list = []
    for i in my_list:
        if input_char.lower() in i.lower():
            ret_list.append(i)
    return ret_list

MyList=["Monkey","Phone","Metro","Boom","Feet"]

input_char=input("Input a character :").strip()  # get a character and strip spaces if any.

find_words(input_char, MyList)  # call the function with arguments
```

Output for sample input "M :

```
Input a character :>? "M"
>>> ['Monkey', 'Metro', 'Boom']
```

Answer (score 0):

(Almost) One liner:

```
>>> MyList=["Monkey","Phone","Metro","Boom","Feet"]
>>> target = input("Input string: ")
Input string: Ph
>>> print([i for i in MyList if target.lower() in i.lower()])
['Phone']
```

Generally in Python you don't want to be playing with indexes, iterators are the way to go.
The `in` keyword checks for substrings so it will work whether you provide only one character or a full string too (i.e. if you input `Ph` you'll get a list containing only `Phone`)

Comment: Can you post output pls? I don't think it answers the question directly and logically it will ask for input `n` times but want to understand your approach

Comment: what do you mean by `dont play with indexes`?and explain where are iterators in your code? Pls, do not throw words here.

Comment: By don't play with indexes I mean elements of a list/string through the syntax `Mylist[index]`. Python already have tools to automate most tasks you could think of, including this one (in that case that would be the `in` keyword).
By iterators I mean the `for item in list` syntax as opposed to C-style indexing done with the variable count in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how efficient you want your search would be. Throwing in one more approach to build a dictionary like this

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(set)
for i in MyList:
    chars = set(i)
    for c in chars:
        d[c].add(i)
```

Now, your dictionary looks like this

```
defaultdict(set,
            {'o': {'Boom', 'Metro', 'Monkey', 'Phone'},
             'k': {'Monkey'},
             'e': {'Feet', 'Metro', 'Monkey', 'Phone'},
             'M': {'Metro', 'Monkey'},
             'y': {'Monkey'},
             'n': {'Monkey', 'Phone'},
             'h': {'Phone'},
             'P': {'Phone'},
             't': {'Feet', 'Metro'},
             'r': {'Metro'},
             'm': {'Boom'},
             'B': {'Boom'},
             'F': {'Feet'}})
```

Now, you can simply search within your dict with O(1) complexity

```
d[your_input_char]
```

Comment: This will cause a massive memory overhead as the list grows bigger.

Comment: Read my first statement first. Thanks. It is always a trade-off between time and space complexity. You need to decide which solution works best for you. It will behave poorly on space complexity but will work well on search. While building a search system I'd care more about speed rather than space.

Comment: I understand that you get O(1) results here, but that's at the cost of a O(A\*N\*S) memory expense, with A being the size of you alphabet, N the number of elements in the list and S the average size of each element. I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: Again throwing ideas here. OP should decide which solution works best for him. I'm still not convinced with the downvote but whatever makes you happy. Cheers

Comment: @Cal The space complexity for the dictionary is `O(A*N)`, since the dictionary has at most A keys and each key has a set containing at most N references to strings. A reference takes `O(1)` space, and the strings already exist in memory; but if you want to count the strings too, then the total is `O((A+S)*N)`, still less than `O(A*N*S)`, and quite an overestimate, since when S < N, each set will not have references to all N strings.

Comment: A tighter bound for the dictionary's space is `O(min(A, S) * N)` because `O(S * N)` is also a bound; each of the `S * N` characters in the original list adds one member to one of the sets in the dictionary. So the space for the dictionary is bounded by a linear function of the space for the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use a list comprehension:

```
def Find(letter, MyList):
    print([word for word in MyList if letter.lower() in word.lower()])

Find('m', ["Monkey","Phone","Metro","Boom","Feet"])
```

Output:

```
['Monkey', 'Metro', 'Boom']
```